# EXC_BREAKPOINT when using self.window?.makeKeyAndView()

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

For some reason when I use `self.window?.makeKeyAndView()` in my AppDelegate, I get the EXC_Breakpoint. When I let the ViewController load in normally via Segue, it doesn't happen.

Basically, my goal with this code is to skip the initial view controller if the user is already logged in.

`AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("auth_token") != nil {
        self.window?.rootViewController = MainViewController()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

`MainViewController.swift`:

This is a chunk of code in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
navTitleLabel1 = UILabel()
navTitleLabel1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: wBounds, height: 20)
navTitleLabel1.text = "View 1" //TRIGGERS EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT)
navTitleLabel1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navTitleLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
self.navbarView.addSubview(navTitleLabel1)

navTitleLabel2 = UILabel()
navTitleLabel2.alpha = 0.0
navTitleLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 8, width: wBounds, height: 20)
navTitleLabel2.text = "View 2"
navTitleLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navTitleLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
self.navbarView.addSubview(navTitleLabel2)
```

When I comment out the line that triggers is the one I commented on, then the next equivalent View 2 string one triggers it. I don't understand why this is happening.

**Edit:**

I fixed it as follows:

```swift
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("auth_token") != nil {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as? UIViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show more information, like the stack trace and anything additional from the console.

However in this case your problem is clear. You make a new view controller by initialising it directly (`MainViewController()`) when you do this none of the information from your storyboard is present, so all of your outlets will be nil, and since they are implicitly unwrapped optionals (`!`) this causes a crash.

The explanation for the crash is clearly printed in the console.

If the content of a VC is defined on the storyboard, you have to load it from the storyboard. Use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Yep, following your advice, I got it. That was exactly the issue.

Comment: Also, is there any reason why I don't have to explicitly state what window is when I use self.window! ? Was it initialized to something before that method call?

Comment: If you have a storyboard, the window gets made for you.